# Realisations of T - affrication

Tags: phonetics, ipa

Spanish T and English T are quite different. I was wondering if the difference is just about laminar/apical realisations. I'm talking about unstressed T; that is, no aspiration included. Recently I found a video where an English man says that English T has something special: affrication. It's not an affricate; it's just a plosive consonant with affrication.
Here is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PSdlctYBsw

What do you think about this? Is English T (at least in most dialects) an apical alveolar plosive with affrication?

Comment: Please state your question more specifically. *"What do you think about this"* seems to be vague and invites for opinions, not for knowledge.

Comment: Initial /t/ in stressed syllables is aspirated heavily in English; if it comes before /r/ in a cluster, it's frequently affricated to a /tʃ/ cluster. I.e, _true_ and _chew_ sound the same to most speakers, just like _bare_ and _bear_, and they are not confused any more often.

Comment: My question is about the non aspirated T (in weak position). And it's not about true affricates. It's about a plosive /t/ with "affrication". It would be [t] with a small s superscripted.

Comment: @jlawler, rounding (due to r) starts earlier for "true"  than it does for "chew". They sure sound different to me.

Comment: @jlawler True, a following /r/ can trigger /t/-affrication, but the /r/ is not entirely lost in the resulting /tʃ/. Hence Greg's comment. A following underlying /j/ can sometimes trigger /t/-affrication, too, as in e.g. future, actual, century, tube.

Comment: I think [t͡ʃɹu:] would be more accurate for "true". But that's harder for me to pronounce than [tɹu:].
At least in British English it's quite common to pronounce [tj] as [t͡ʃ].

Comment: None of these variations are regular or rule-governed. They're part of the range of normal variation, which may be socially-governed or simply individual. This range swamps a lot of other variables.

Comment: About *t* being unaspirated. Which "weak"/"unstressed" positions do you mean? I have heard the claim that /t/ would be unaspirated in final position but while that can happen especially when unreleased I have been actively looking out for unaspirated final /t/s and have come to the conclusion that even final /t/ is usually heavily aspirated if it is released.

Comment: I'd say it's a feature of SSB (Standard South British, Lindsey's term) rather than of RP. You may want to read Chapter 14 *More aspiration (and affrication)* in Lindsey 2019 *English after RP* https://www.palgrave.com/gp/book/9783030043568

Answer (score 2):

Geoff Lindsey does has this affrication feature in his pronunciation of /t/ – his pronunciation doesn't strike me as strange, just British. [Honeybone](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/homes/patrick/livlen.pdf) discusses similar lenition in Liverpudlian which includes [ts] realizations. It is probably true for some range of UK dialects. I can't say that I've heard this from any American English speakers, but sub-phonemic details are easy to miss: it's certainly not present in my local dialect. Dialects can't be meaningfully counted, so questions about "most" can't be resolved. At present, I don't believe there has been a systematic survey of where this affrication shows up. FWIW, the same thing happens in Siswati and the dialect of Arabic spoken by many Berber speakers, and it is connected to aspiration. His realizations of /t/ in unaspirated contexts is not affricated by comparison to the aspirated allophone (I didn't do a systematic acoustic study), so I suspect it is an enhancement feature for aspiration.

Comment: I'm more used to British English and I've noticed this feature in pretty much all English English accents. I'll pay more attention to American accents. Thank you so much for your explanation.